# Slideshow missing when page loads?

Tags: slideshow

I have a simple example to illustrate my problem here.

http://www.ttmt.org.uk/forum/wordpress-forum/

It's just one page, home.php.

The home page has a list of images that are made into a slideshow.

From Settings > Reading > Front page display, I have selected the home page as the Front page.

The home page loads but without the slideshow.

If I click 'Home' to reload the home page the slideshow appears.

Why does the slideshow not appear when the page opens.

Comment: There's not enough information here for anyone to help out, are you using a plugin, default themes, jquery, etc... please add more information and examples of coding on the page.

Comment: Note related to wordpress - misconfigured JavaScript doing all this stuff.

Comment: It is *partially* related to WordPress, because WordPress uses no-conflict for jQuery, which does impact the OP's issue.

Answer (score 2):

The name `home.php` is reserved for use by the [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) as the *Blog Posts Index*. To create a custom template for the *Site Front Page*, use **`front-page.php`**.

Another issue: your slideshow [jQuery script needs to have a no-conflict wrapper](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_wrappers), and should not execute until the page is loaded.

Instead of this:

```
$(function()
```

...you need to use this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($)
```

## Edit

Aside from those two issues, I'm not sure your problem is WordPress-specific.

I notice that you're including jQuery cycle *before* you include jQuery itself. I'm not sure if that would cause issues or not.

## Edit 2

From your comment:

> The Theme contains...front-page.php (static page that is the front page)

I suspect that this is somehow contributing to your problem. The `front-page.php` file is **not** a *static page* but rather a *Theme template file*. A static page is not an actual file, but merely a database entry - a *post* with a *post-type* of *page*. A Theme template file is a file that WordPress uses to output content based on the current context.

Please review the [Codex entry for creating a static front page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page), and ensure you're following all instructions correctly. Once you've got your static front page configured properly, let's see if the problem persists.

Comment: I followed your suggestions, changed the name of home.php and the jquery - still not working. The slideshow loads but it's just a thin strip, the rest seems to be hidden. If you scroll left/right near the nav you can see the rest of the slideshow

Comment: Another question: I notice that the *page name* changed from *Home* to *Front Page*. What template files are included in your Theme, and what static Page are you using for the front page?

Comment: The theme contains: footer.php, front-page.php (static page that is the front page), functions.php, header.php and index.php.

I tried to replicate the situation outside Wordpress, but it works then - http://www.ttmt.org.uk/cyclegallery/

I think the cycle link might come before the jquery because I was following the advise here and getting the jquery in the functions.php - http://wpmu.org/using-jquery-with-wordpress-a-quick-crash-course-and-performance-tips/

Comment: See updated answer in re: `front-page.php` and proper configuration of a static front page. Regarding your jQuery enqueueing: please post the relevant `functions.php` code in your answer.

Comment: The static front page was set up as described in the Codex. I think my terminology might have confused the matter. front-page.php is the template I'm using for the page. This is the code used in the functions.php - `<?php
 
function my_init() {

 if (!is_admin()) {
 // comment out the next two lines to load the local copy of jQuery
 wp_deregister_script('jquery');
 wp_register_script('jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js', false, '1.3.2');
 wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
 }
}
add_action('init', 'my_init');  

?>`

Comment: And how are you enqueueing the jQuery Cycle plugin?

Comment: By enqueueing do you mean how and when I'm I loading the cycle plugin? I was loading the plugin in the header. If I don't load the plugin the slideshow still works. I'm using the NextGen Gallery which looks like it loads the cycle plugin. So if I don't load the plugin Wordpress loads the jquery then NextGen loads the cycle plugin.